# How to read csv to divide values to a few columns in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, read.csv

I have Table in csv like below:

|  | date | col1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.04.2020 | 111 |
| 2 | 05.11.2019 | 2 |
| 3 | 22.05.2018 | 86 |

But when I try to read abowe csv in Python Pandas using below code:

```
df= pd.read_csv("my_data.csv")
```

I have Data Frame like below (it does not look good):

|  | ;date;col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1;01.04.2020;111 |
| 1 | 2;05.11.2019;2 |
| 2 | 3;22.05.2018;86 |

How can I modify my code to read this csv and as output have Data Frame in elegant form like in csv ?

Comment: You need to add `sep=";"` and `index_col=0` to `read_csv()`.  [Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) is the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your csv is using `;` as a delimiter, instead of the default `,`.

You might also wanna instruct pandas to use the first column as index.

Use `df = pd.read_csv("my_data.csv", delimiter=';', index_col=0)`

Answer (score 1):

As Rawson wrote, you need `df= pd.read_csv("my_data.csv", sep=";")`